# ASP.NET Core -JSON Ignore not working for Get Request

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

In ASP.NET Core Web API, I implemented Json Ignore IN Swashbuckle Swagger
So I did as shown below:

```
public class QueryChequeBookRequestDto : GetCreateChequeDetailDto
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Account Number field is required.")]
    [JsonProperty("AccountNumber")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}

public class GetCreateChequeDetailDto
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("AdmissionNumber")]
    public string AdmissionNumber { get; set; } = null;

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("SchoolCode")]
    public string SchoolCode { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ChequeBookController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IChequeBooksServices _chequeBooksServices;
    public ChequeBookController(
        IChequeBooksServices chequeBooksServices
        )
    {
        _chequeBooksServices = chequeBooksServices;
    }

    [HttpGet("QueryChequeBook")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetQueryChqueBookAsync([FromQuery] QueryChequeBookRequestDto chequeBookDto)
    {
        var result = await _chequeBooksServices.GetQueryChequeBookAsync(chequeBookDto);
        return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
    }
 }
```

I don't want AdmissionNumber and SchoolCode to appear at all (I want them hidden) It's working on HttpPost, but it's not working on HttpGet.

What I mean is that AdmissionNumber and SchoolCode are not visible on swagger in HttpPost (which is what I want). But are still visible on swagger in HttpGet. Why are AdmissionNumber and SchoolCode still visible on swagger in HttpGet

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please explain "not working". Also please provide a [mre] including the swagger setup.

Comment: @GuruStron - What I mean is that AdmissionNumber and SchoolCode are not visible on swagger in HttpPost (which is what I want). But are still visible on swagger in HttpGet. Why are AdmissionNumber and SchoolCode still visible on swagger in HttpGet

Comment: are you sure using same class for `POST ` and `GET`

Comment: @UpenderReddy - I didn't say I'm using same class for POST  and GET.  I called the same model in POST Request, it hides the two fields on the swagger (which is what I want), but it's not the same on GET

Comment: can you share  your Controller code

Comment: @UpenderReddy - I have added the updated the code. The controller is there

Comment: you didn't motion in Query sting from starting. I that it in response. so any way given the answer Check.

Comment: Without fromquery, it works for both get and post in my test. Is there any difference to use bindnever or just commentary a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to get ignore Properties from a class in `[FromQuery]` need to decorate Property with `[BindNever]` as follows.

```
   public class GetCreateChequeDetailDto
    {
        [BindNever]
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("AdmissionNumber")]
        public string AdmissionNumber { get; set; } = null;

        [BindNever]
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("SchoolCode")]
        public string SchoolCode { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

for more follow this [link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1748)